# CharIndex query it bring back the wrong values?

Tags: sql-server

I have a CSV file I have imported into a table in SQL Server. I'm doing a`charindex`to get the position on the each comma! What Rocky mistake am I making here?

```
    SELECT-- a.string_raw, 
    charindex(',',a.string_raw,1) string_raw_1,
    charindex(',',a.string_raw,2) string_raw_2,
    charindex(',',a.string_raw,3) string_raw_3,
    charindex(',',a.string_raw,4) string_raw_4
    FROM raw_data A
```

Sample string:

```
,1.30pm,PW Cooper,7,11,,07/09/2014,tbc,,
```

The results are coming back as

```
    string_raw_1 = 1 Correct
    string_raw_2 = 8 Correct
    String_raw_3 = 8 wrong
    String_raw_4 = 8 wrong
```

If someone could give me the answer that would be ace! I have a feeling that this one will make me look foolish

Comment: What's your `string_raw`?

Comment: third parameter is the starting position not the occurence

Comment: ,1.30pm,PW Cooper,7,11,,07/09/2014,tbc,,

Comment: SQL Server has pretty poor string processing facilities. You might want to consider some simple text operations that make the string resemble xml (e.g. replace `,` with `</a><a>`, add suitable start and end parts onto the string) and the converting to XML - you could then write xpath expressions to extract the components you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are expecting values like 1, 8, 7, 6 since you are increasing the startindex parameter. If you expect the functions to return 1, 8, 18, 20 see @Thomas Haratyk 's comment.

The return value of `CHARINDEX` is counted from the beginning of the string, not from the startindex position:

```
                 1 2  22
1      8         8 0  34
,1.30pm,PW Cooper,7,11,,07/09/2014,tbc,
```